# Installing update-manager-core in Natty 11.04

Tags: installation, 11.04, apt, update-manager

My Ubuntu Version (Server):

```
root@li339-83:~# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 11.04
Release:        11.04
Codename:       natty
root@li339-83:~#
```

When I do `apt-get install update-manager-core`

I get the following error:

```
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty-updates/main update-manager-core i386 1:0.150.5.4
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty-security/main update-manager-core i386 1:0.150.5.4
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8c01::23 80]
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/u/update-manager/update-manager-core_0.150.5.4_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8c01::23 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Running `apt-get install --fix-missing update-manager-core`

results in:

```
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty-updates/main update-manager-core i386 1:0.150.5.4
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty-security/main update-manager-core i386 1:0.150.5.4
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8c01::23 80]
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/u/update-manager/update-manager-core_0.150.5.4_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8c01::23 80]
E: Internal Error, ordering was unable to handle the media swap
```

After installing and running banish404,

```
root@li339-83:~# apt-get install update-manager-core
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package update-manager-core
```

Seems banish404 was partially installed:

```
root@li339-83:~# apt-get dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 banish404 : Depends: zenity but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

Trying using dist-upgrade:

```
root@li339-83:~# sudo apt-get -f dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  banish404
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 45.1 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
(Reading database ... 26880 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing banish404 ...
root@li339-83:~# sudo apt-get -f dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
root@li339-83:~#
```

Have added more debug details here - http://pastebin.com/n6yDwHGh

I am not sure why Ubuntu is not able to do such a simple task. Do I need to modify sources.list?

Comment: Have you reviewed [this post](http://askubuntu.com/q/65911/62483)?

Comment: Trying to install banish404 now..

Comment: @Lucio after removing all 404 repos, getting above error

Comment: Have you tried with `sudo apt-get -f dist-upgrade`?

Comment: @Lucio Nope. Updated question.

Comment: Take a look at [this post](http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies). I think that you will find a solution there. Also, what version of Ubuntu are you using? Is it Desktop or Server edition?

Comment: @Lucio It is a server version 11.04. Added a pastebin link with entire details. Do you know which PPA has update-manager-core?

Comment: No, I don't know. Tell me your results trying with the previously mentioned link.

Comment: @Lucio Its here - http://pastebin.com/n6yDwHGh

Comment: Have you run `sudo apt-get update` recently? If not, try it now

Comment: @jackweirdy doesnt help. Updated pastebin link with the results.

Comment: Try just using `update-manager`, not including the `-core` suffix

Comment: @jackweirdy `E: Unable to locate package update-manager`

Comment: Are you running Natty? Natty is EOL.

Comment: @Seth Yes. So there is no way to install update-manager-core in Natty?

Comment: Please see http://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-old-unsupported-release

Comment: @Seth Him is running the Server edition. I think that this is not EOL.

Comment: @Seth @Lucio I used this [answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/121642/164420) replacing karmic with natty. and I successfully installed update-manager-core. Now I updated `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades` to Prompt=ltr and when I do `sudo do-release-upgrade` I see `No new release found`

Comment: I Changed to Prompt=normal and updating to 11.10 for now

Comment: Finally updated to 12.04 LTS !!